# MongoDB Golang driver trying to connect to localhost instead of docker host

Tags: mongodb, docker, go, docker-compose

**ERROR**

```
app        | 2020/07/14 13:19:00 server selection error: server selection timeout, current topology: { Type: Unknown, Servers: [{ Addr: localhost:27017, Type: Unknown, State: Connected, Average RTT: 0, Last error: connection() : dial tcp 127.0.0.1:27017: connect: connection refused }, ] }
```

I am using docker-compose to manage golang app and mongo db (without replica set) instances. docker-compose file contents:

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    container_name: mongodb
    restart: always
    ports:
          - 27017:27017
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: local
    command: mongod --bind_ip mongodb


  app:
    image: app:1.4
    container_name: app
    environment:
      - MONGO_URL=mongodb
    ports:
         - 80:8080
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
    restart: always
```

Running Docker Containers:

```
docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                      NAMES
d130336be71e        app:1.4   "/app/main"              4 minutes ago       Up 2 seconds        0.0.0.0:80->8080/tcp       app
dc57dd2de645        mongo                "docker-entrypoint.s…"   4 minutes ago       Up 2 seconds        0.0.0.0:27017->27017/tcp   mongodb
```

**For Connecting Golang app with MongoDB**

I am using official mongodb go driver (go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo) and my code is trying to connect to docker host (mongodb):

```
var dbUser string = "root"
var dbPassword string = "local"
dbURL := os.Getenv("MONGO_URL")
clientOptions := options.Client()
    clientOptions.SetDirect(true).ApplyURI("mongodb://" + dbUser + ":" + dbPassword + "@" + dbURL +":27017/?connect=direct")
```

**Troubleshooting**

1. As part of trying to figure out what is wrong I looked at similar issues highlighted in stackoverflow and tried below options:

   - Tried to use connect=direct in connection URI
   - Tried to use [SetDirect](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options#ClientOptions.SetDirect)
   - Added --bindip as highlighted in my docker-compose file
2. I logged-in into the app container and tried to ping mongodb and it worked:

```
root@d130336be71e:/app# ping mongodb
PING mongodb (172.18.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from mongodb.app_default (172.18.0.2): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.159 ms
64 bytes from mongodb.app_default (172.18.0.2): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.200 ms
64 bytes from mongodb.app_default (172.18.0.2): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.079 ms
64 bytes from mongodb.app_default (172.18.0.2): icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.087 ms
64 bytes from mongodb.app_default (172.18.0.2): icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.083 ms
^C
--- mongodb ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 60ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.079/0.121/0.200/0.050 ms
```

After trying these options, I am seeking help from Golang community as I am fairly new to Golang.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You are telling the driver to connect to localhost I guess. Remove environment variable stuff from the question and replace with literal values.

Comment: When you are pinging - you are using host alias, not the env variable. Also try to view MONGO_URL variable - I think it is not defined.

Comment: I tried to use the literal value of docker host which didn't work either as I got the same error. And MONGO_URL variable is defined in container env. I validated it.